# Intermittent mySQL crash. phpmyadmin logs me out when I click on variables tab

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm on the LAMP stack with heavyreliance on mysql and PHP.

the problem seems to get worse when I take the game out of maintenance mode: at that point I can't even log into phpmyadmin.  the mysql server shuts down and restarts on it's own.  I need to get a hold of the stacktrace or error log I guess.

Also, this problem started when the server went down from our host yesterday: but this happens every week for the last 6 months and we've always just restarted everything, and everything would be fine after that.  But not this time.

Also, whenever I click on the 'Variables' tab, I get logged out of phpmyadmin.

And it looks like when I try to click on the table in phpmyadmin: information_schema, there is an error

SQL query: DocumentationEdit

SELECT tracking_active
FROM  `phpmyadmin`.`pma_tracking`
WHERE  `db_name` =  'information_schema'
AND  `table_name` =  'PARTITIONS'
ORDER BY version DESC

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

doing a check on that table yeilds this:
information_schema.TABLES   check   note    The storage engine for the table doesn't support check

Comment: But my problem shouldn't be a configuration thing because I haven't changed any configurations in the last month, and neither has my host.

Comment: I have a strange error with that too -- never figured it out :(